# Algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters

Tags: java, algorithm, java.util.scanner

I have written this algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters, but its giving me some errors. Can anyone help me with improving the code.

It is giving me the error that I am duplicating the `uniquechar1` method but I am passing it to an `if` statement.

```
package nospacesinstrings;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class uniquechar {

    public static boolean uniquechar1(String s) {

        if (s == null || s.length() > 0 ) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0 ;i < s.length();i++) {
            for (int j = s.length() ;j > 0;j--) {
                if (i == j)
                   return false;
                else 
                   return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s ;
        System.out.println("Enter the string ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = in.nextLine(); 
        if (uniquechar1(s) == true) {
            System.out.println("String has all the unique characters ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("String does not have all the unique characters ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use if (uniquechar1(s)) instead, your algorithm is wrong however

Comment: That reduces errors.But how do i fix the algorithm

Comment: yes i fixed the error you pointed out but the algorithm still doesn't work

Comment: you don't have to believe everything I say, test your code, if it works then great, otherwise debug it. This how you learn programming

Comment: "It is giving me the error that I am duplicating the `uniquechar1` method" - when telling people about errors, it's useful to include the full and exact text of the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your check at the top looks backwards. I think you meant to put `s.length() < 1` instead of `s.length() > 0`

You also are returning a value before you have finished iterating over your string. You should only return `true` if you iteration through the complete string without returning `false`

Also, your double loop will always end up comparing each character to itself so the method will return false. To do it using a for each loop, you need to stop before you get to the currently checked index.

```
for (int i = 0 ;i < s.length();i++){
    for (int j = s.length() ;j > i;j--){
        if (i == j )
        {return false ;}
    }
return true;
```

you could also avoid traversing twice down the string by collecting characters as you go. Something like this:

```
Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
for (int i = 0 ;i < s.length();i++){
        if (stack.Contains(s[i]))
        {return false ;}
        stack.Push(s[i]);
    }
return true ;
```

Lastly, if you should research character comparison. Are you looking to fail if any two any character even if they are different cases (i.e. A == a or A != a)?

Answer (score -1):

This algorithm should work. I'm assuming there are no numbers in the string. (Edited to correct code).

```
public static boolean uniquechar1(String s) 
{
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0 )
        return true;
    // make sure no letter in alphabet occurs twice in the string.
    boolean[] letters = new boolean[26];
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        ch = (char) (ch - 'A');

        if (letters[ch] == true)
            return false;
        else
            letters[ch] = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is a tester method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println( uniquechar1("Hello World!") );
    System.out.println( uniquechar1("A A") );   
    System.out.println( uniquechar1("ABC") );   
}
```

Outputs:

```
false  
false  
true
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a boolean array of 26 ? Secondly what does ch = ch - 'A' means?

Comment: There are 26 letters in the alphabet. In programming, `char` types are usually represented as ASCII code, meaning they are integers in disguise and arithmetic operations may be performed on them. So something like `'A' - 'A'` equals 0, `'B' - 'A'` equals 1, etc...

Comment: In ch = (char) (ch - 'A'); why are we only subtracting characters from A,What about the rest of the alphabets ?

Comment: `s.toUpperCase()` and `s.replaceAll(" ", "")` makes the string all capital letters and removes all spaces. This means we can see how many characters away any letter is from `'A'`.

Comment: How does the length of a character from the letter A helps with anything ?Lets say the letter is D. ch = (char) (ch - 'A'); will cast 3 as char in this case and then assign it to ch .Is that right ?

Comment: Also whats happening here ?" if (letters[ch] == true) " In what case ch will be false ? can you give an example?

Comment: Yes. And every element of the letters[] array begins as false, the element only becomes true when the correct letter is found.